# NamedItem method with getElementByTagName in Chrome don't work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this code in javascript:

```
var prop="author";
var optele = theform.getElementsByTagName("input");
alert(optele[prop]);
```

but in Chrome it returns **"undefined"** even though I'm sure that the "author" tag exists.
Instead, work well in IE and Firefox.

But I noticed that  there is a "namedItem" method in optele var in IE and Firefox but there isn't in Chrome.

Someone can help me to run similar code syntax on Chrome?

Comment: is this in a dom ready scope?

Comment: What the heck do you mean by "*the "author" tag exists*"? Please show us your markup. And no, the returned `NodeList` will not have a `author` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because IE and FF return a [`HTMLCollection` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection) instead of a [`NodeList` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList). `NodeList`'s don't have a way of extracting an element by name or ID (what the [`namedItem` method *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection#Methods) does).

The solution is to not use this feature, but instead iterate over the nodes and compare the `name` property. Alternatively you could use [`document.getElementsByName` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).

From the MDN [`getElementsByTagName` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName):

> **Note:** While the W3C specification says `elements` is a `NodeList`, this method returns a `HTMLCollection` both in Gecko and Internet Explorer. Opera returns a `NodeList`, but with a `namedItem` method implemented, which makes it similar to a `HTMLCollection`. As of January 2012, only in WebKit browsers is the returned value a pure `NodeList`. See [bug 14869](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14869) for details.